# Sparse complex matrices are undefined for GSL

Tags: c, matrix, sparse-matrix, complex-numbers, gsl

I want to create a sparse complex matrix in GSL and their documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/spmatrix.html) says that all functions are available for several matrix types, with the one interesting to me being **gsl_spmatrix_complex**.

> All the functions are available for each of the standard data-types. The versions for double have the prefix gsl_spmatrix, Similarly the versions for single-precision float arrays have the prefix gsl_spmatrix_float.

I tried to use `gsl_spmatrix_complex_alloc` to allocate one and get an undefined reference in GCC.

```
gsl_spmatrix mat = gsl_spmatrix_complex_alloc(matrix_header.m, matrix_header.n);
```

I thought that maybe my includes were wrong (`gsl/gsl_spmatrix.h` and then trying things like `gsl/gsl_matrix_complex_double.h`) but then I run `cat /usr/include/gsl/* | grep gsl_spmatrix_complex` and I get no results, so either my `libgsl-dev` (Ubuntu 20.04) is broken or the documentation is wrong. No allocation functions and no matrix functions at all for sparse complex types!

Given the docs use `gsl_spmatrix_float` as an example, I did a grep on that too and nothing exists.

So back to my question, how can I create a sparse complex matrix in GSL as per the docs?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `libgsl-dev` is at v2.5 on Ubuntu 20.04 but at v2.6 on Ubuntu 20.10 so the problem is indeed my distro and not the package. Downloading the package and compiling manually will solve the problem.